# Doesn't the script terminate when user aborts in PHP?

Tags: php

As given here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

> Sometimes it is handy to always have your scripts run to completion even if there is no remote browser receiving the output.
> The default behaviour is however for your script to be aborted when
> the remote client disconnects.

But I have a data scraping script which, after given input initiates a bootstrap process to fetch data and write it in a file. Albeit I have'nt given `ignore_user_abort`, even after closing the script window, it keep running in background, the data still being written. Shoud'nt the process itself terminate when the window is closed? and if that being true, is'nt `ignore_user_abort` futile?

Comment: The script will be 'walking dead' once the user terminates their connection. Generally speaking it should be killed, but MAY continue running until it attempts to perform any output. ignore_user_abort() simply guarantees that it WILL continue running when the connection is closed.

Comment: @MarcB: `walking dead`  :). How do you ensure the converse?: To die when user aborts?

Comment: There's `connection_aborted()` and `connection_status()` so you can check for disconnects manually. As far as automatic stuff, basically it only happens when you do output.